# Installed Visual Studio 2015 and ASP.NET 5. Created an Empty website and when I run it I get Error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

Image one shows error when I try to host is to IIS and second image is error when I run project using IIS express

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9iYi.png]

Comment: Did you make *any* changes to the project created by VS or you get this error even with the default app?

Comment: What dnx are you running on?

Comment: Copy and paste the text of the errors, rather than posting images. Text is much easier to read, and much more friendly to users reading from mobile devices.

Comment: A) Does it work without the debugger (CTL+F5)?
B) Did you enable windows auth? Turn it off, it breaks the debugger.

Comment: The DNX version is 1.0.0-rc1-16231

Comment: C:\>dnvm version
1.0.0-rc1-15540

C:\>dnx --version
Microsoft .NET Execution environment
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16231
 Type:         CoreClr
 Architecture: x64
 OS Name:      Windows
 OS Version:   10.0
 Runtime Id:   win10-x64

C:\>dnvm list

Active Version           Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------------- -----
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          win             default
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          win
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86         win

Comment: Have you tried following this guide - https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html - to enable the httpplatformhandler?